# edit array elements and capitalize the letters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have array

```
var myarr = [ "color - black", "color - blue", "color - Red" ]
```

I want to replace " - " with ":" and capitalize the first letter

```
var myarr = [ "Color: black", "Color: blue", "Color: Red" ]
```

I try this but I don't know how to capitalize the first letter

```
for(var i=0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
            myarr[i] = myarr[i].replace(/ - /g, ":");
        }
```

Comment: Here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026069/capitalize-the-first-letter-of-string-in-javascript

Comment: And from where do you get your array? Couldn't you change it before filling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var myarr = [ "color - black", "color - blue", "color - Red" ]

for(var i=0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
  myarr[i] = myarr[i][0].toUpperCase() + myarr[i].replace(/ -/g, ":").substring(1);
}

console.log(myarr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i=0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
        myarr[i] = myarr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + myarr[i].replace(/ - /g, ":").substring(1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
for(var i=0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
    myarr[i] = myarr[i].replace(/ - /g, ":");
    myarr[i] = myarr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + myarr[i].slice(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map to create a new array. I've capitalised both the word 'color' and the actual color:

```
var myarr = ["color - black", "color - blue", "color - Red"];

var newArray = myarr.map(function(element) {
  var tmp = element.split("color - ")[1];
  return "Color: " + tmp.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + tmp.slice(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Array.map()` method this way:

```js
var myarr = ["color - black", "color - blue", "color - Red"];

var nArr = myarr.map(function(str) {
  var s = str.replace(/-/g, ":");
  var a = s.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.slice(1, s.length);
  return a;
});
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(nArr);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```